# SQL Server 2008 R2 : how to disable the remote access only for the user "sa"?

Tags: sql-server, remote-access

The title says it pretty well: I can access my SQL Server from the internet, and my users are configured with strong passwords to access only their respective DBs.

But I receive 10000+ login attacks by day with the user "sa".

I don't need "sa" remote access, how to disable it, and only it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security practices by Microsoft and industry state if use SQL authentication to rename the sa account and disable it. There is really no reason to use that account explicity for an application or admin account. Most companies require tracability when it comes to security and use of the sa account in SQL server does not allow for that.

Even if you disable or rename it you will still see attacks coming in for that account, it comes with the territory. The same thing occurs with the default login Oracle has in their product. Script kiddies and other hacking programs are just programmed to check for those type of accounts.

A better option might be to report where the attacks are coming from on the network side to your network team or ISP. They will be able to better handle that to block that traffic through the network layer. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=151103) might help: in conjunction with [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/126511/disable-remote-access-for-one-user-database-in-sql-server-2008):

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know SQL Server lets you diable single sql server logins, but that means the login is disabled in general, regardless of the machine the user is trying to connect from. So you either disable "sa" in general or you'll have give the login a really strong password. You might be able to emulate the desired behavior by using a logon trigger, that checks where the user connects from, if the user is "sa", but i think that's not a viable solution for you, since you seem to be wanting to get rid of the many connection attempts from attacks. In any case, you might want to remove "sa" from the server role "sysadmin" to guard against a potentially successful login attemt.